# Drop columns containing specific characters in title whilst moving values under those columns to nearest left side column

Tags: r, rstudio

Okay clearly by the title you can see my logic is out the window. So i'll try my best to be clear with my objective.

I have 10 columns with 2 rows, one containing the column names, and the other containing topic names.

```
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10         #(Column Count)
Name1   ---     ---     Name2   ---     ---     Name3   ---     ---     Name4      #(Column Names)[Row1]
Topic1  Topic2  Topic3  Topic4  Topic5  Topic6  Topic7  Topic8  Topic9  Topic10    #(Topic Names)[Row2]
```

Basically I want to remove all columns containing "---" But move the values under those columns to the nearest left side column that wasn't dropped. So desired execution should look like this:

```
1       2       3       4     
Name1   Name2   Name3   Name4           
Topic1  Topic4  Topic7  Topic10
Topic2  Topic5  Topic8
Topic3  Topic6  Topic9
```

Comment: Iss it a data.frame

Comment: Yeah it's a data.frame

Comment: the column names are `1`, `2`, etc?

Comment: Column names are ```"Name1"   "---"     "---"     "Name2"   "---"     "---"     "Name3"   "---"     "---"     "Name4"```. The numbers are just counting the columns for reference

Comment: ok, sorry, i was thinking that the numbers are the column names becauses data.frame column name can't be duplicated

Comment: You're right, my bad for that

Comment: updated my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use

```
library(zoo)
df2 <- transform(stack(df1),  
      ind = na.locf0(replace(ind,  grepl('---', ind), NA))) 
lst1 <- split(df2$values, as.character(df2$ind))
out <- do.call(cbind, lapply(lst1, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst1))))
out
#     Name1    Name2    Name3    Name4    
#[1,] "Topic1" "Topic4" "Topic7" "Topic10"
#[2,] "Topic2" "Topic5" "Topic8" NA       
#[3,] "Topic3" "Topic6" "Topic9" NA
```

---

Or another option is to reshape into 'long' format and then convert back to 'wide' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>% 
    pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
    mutate(name = na_if(name, "---")) %>%
    fill(name) %>% 
    mutate(rn = rowid(name)) %>% 
    select(name, value, rn) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>%
    select(-rn)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  Name1  Name2  Name3  Name4  
#  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  
#1 Topic1 Topic4 Topic7 Topic10
#2 Topic2 Topic5 Topic8 <NA>   
#3 Topic3 Topic6 Topic9 <NA>
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name1 = "Topic1", `---` = "Topic2", `---` = "Topic3", 
    Name2 = "Topic4", `---` = "Topic5", `---` = "Topic6", Name3 = "Topic7", 
    `---` = "Topic8", `---` = "Topic9", Name4 = "Topic10"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @srb633 I showed two. solutions and have a reproducible data in my post

Comment: Sorry, just saw your second now. Will try now

Comment: @srb633 please ues the data. from my post

Comment: Can't tell just yet if they've worked. I've got to go, will report back in about 12 hours. Thanks so far.